# Как получить значение т-статистики?

Tags: python, scipy

Я хочу рассчитать доверительный интервал с использованием распределения Стьюдента. Входные данные

```
x_hat = 89.9
sd    = 11.3
n     = 20
```

Степени свободны и отклонение:

```
df = n-1
se = sd/math.sqrt(n)
```

Рассчитываем доверительный интервал:

```
[x_hat - sigma * se, x_hat + sigma * se]
```

При том сигму предлагается брать из [таблицы](https://www.medcalc.org/manual/t-distribution.php). В моем случае, для 95% интервала с `df = 19` значение 2.093.

Каким образом получить это значение сигмы в коде? Я пробую

```
stats.t.ppf(0.95, df)
```

Но на выходе получаю 1.729, то есть значение для 90%.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Рассчитывать значение необходимо действительно с использованием процентной функции `ppf`, однако значение должно рассчитываться иначе:

```
alfa = 1. - 0.95
stats.t.ppf(1. - alfa / 2., df)
```

Дополнительно:

- Похожий вопрос для нормального распределения: «[Scipy - two tail ppf function for a z value?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29562808/564240)»